# Update only selected field in while loop using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a data in my shopping cart coming from database and session in while loop. The problem is that when I try to update the quantity using the following code it updates all the fields. I want to update only that particular field for which I am either increasing or decreasing the quantity in the cart. I have eliminated unnecessary fields here.

Code:

```
<?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){ extract($row);
<td>
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field=""><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="100" value="1">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Increase or Decrease Cart Quantity
  var quantity = 1;
  $('.quantity-right-plus').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var quantity = parseInt($('.quantity').val());
    $('.quantity').val(quantity + 1);
  });
  $('.quantity-left-minus').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var quantity = parseInt($('.quantity').val());
    if(quantity > 1){
        $('.quantity').val(quantity - 1);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the corresponding quantity input box like following `var el = $(this).closest(".input-group").find(".quantity");`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Increase or Decrease Cart Quantity
  var quantity = 1;
  $('.quantity-right-plus').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this).closest(".input-group").find(".quantity");
    var quantity = parseInt(el.val());
    el.val(quantity + 1);
  });
  $('.quantity-left-minus').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this).closest(".input-group").find(".quantity");
    var quantity = parseInt(el.val());
    if (quantity > 1) {
      el.val(quantity - 1);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-danger btn-number" data-type="minus" data-field=""><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="100" value="1">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Perfect... Thanks :)

Comment: @AurazoScript - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use "this" as root so that you get only the specific .quantity and not an array of all matches. so inside the .click function you do this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find(".quantity").val(quantity-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra number:

```html
<?php 
  $num = 1;
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){ extract($row);
?>
<td>
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="" data-target="quantity-<?php echo $num; ?>"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity-<?php echo $num; ?>" min="1" max="100" value="1">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="" data-target="quantity-<?php echo $num; ?>"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
<?php
num ++;
 } ?>
```

And in jQuery:

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
// Increase or Decrease Cart Quantity
  var quantity = 1;
  $('.quantity-right-plus').click(function(e){
    var target = this.data("target");
    e.preventDefault();
    var quantity = parseInt($('input[name="quantity-'+target+'"]').val());
    $('input[name="quantity-'+target+'"]').val(quantity + 1);
  });
  $('.quantity-left-minus').click(function(e){
    var target = this.data("target");
    e.preventDefault();
    var quantity = parseInt($('input[name="quantity-'+target+'"]').val());
    if(quantity > 1){
        $('input[name="quantity-'+target+'"]').val(quantity - 1);
    }
  });
});
```